# Accessing app setting from aspx and add concatenated text

Tags: asp.net, appsettings

I've got a project where I'm tasked with changing hard-coded domain references from one domain to another in a group of legacy C#/VB web projects.  I want to parameterize the domains as much as possible instead of just replacing with a different hard-coded value.  The problem is that there are over 800 of these references in about 30 different solutions, so creating variables in each code-behind to bind to would take forever.

I have added the new domains to the appSettings section of the web.config file, and this works:

```
<asp:HyperLink Text="Link" NavigateUrl="<%$appSettings:DomainX %>" runat="server" />
```

But I need to be able to do something like this:

```
<asp:HyperLink Text="Link" NavigateUrl="<%$appSettings:DomainX %>/newPage.aspx" runat="server" />
```

But when I add the "/newPage.aspx" the page doesn't compile anymore.  I don't really care if this is done with an asp:HyperLink tag or just a  tag.

Any ideas on how I can accomplish this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you have two options. The easiest is to just use a plain old anchor tag, if you're not doing anything with the `HyperLink` server side:

```
<a href="<%= string.Concat(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DomainX"], "/newPage.aspx") %>">Link</a>
```

Alternatively, you could set the `NavigateUrl` in the `Page_Load`, since <%= will not work properly within the `HyperLink` server tag:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!Page.IsPostBack)
        link1.NavigateUrl = string.Concat("http://", 
                  ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DomainX"], "/newPage.aspx");
}
```

You could also see if you can make a custom binding, something like `$myBinding:DomainX`, but I don't know if that's possible off the top of my head (I would assume it is though).

**EDIT**
That `$appSettings:DomainX` code is called an ASP.NET Expression, and can you can create custom expressions. This [post](http://haacked.com/archive/2006/11/29/Express_Yourself_With_Custom_Expression_Builders.aspx) from Phil Haack covers how to set them up, in case you are interested.

Comment: Thanks, this works great.  I guess the trick was just to get rid of the asp:HyperLink tag.  I was actually even able to remove the string.Concat to save some characters:
`<a href="<%= Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings("DomainX") + "/newPage.aspx" %>">Link</a>`
(WebConfigurationManager vs. ConfigurationManager because the page I was testing on was backed by VB)

Comment: @Mike Glad that worked out for you. If you like this answer and want to accept it, you can just click the check mark under score on the left.

Answer (score 2):

How about something along the lines of:

```
<%=ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DomainX"].ToString() + "/newPage.aspx" %>
```

Comment: No need to call `.ToString()` on something that is already a string.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with one of two different approaches that would save you the need to change the `NavigateUrl` in the `.aspx` itself.

One option is to inherit from HyperLink class and overriding the `NavigateUrl` property, adding the `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DomainX"]` in the getter method. Having this, just change `<asp:HyperLink ...` to `<UC:MyLink ...`

Second option is adding small function to each page (can be in one shared place and just called from each page) that will iterate over all the hyperlinks controls and dynamically add the domain. To find all controls of certain type you can use [such code](http://programcsharp.com/blog/archive/2008/01/02/Recursively-find-controls-by-type-with-generics.aspx) for example.